# How to get text from nested elements

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, request, cheerio

I have a list of available jobs which I have stored in my temp variable. I want the text of a few elements from those jobs individually. How can I get a text from nested classes?

In the code below, I am getting empty lines printed to my console when trying to access the text.

```
const request = require('request')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

url = 'https://www.temp.com/jobs'

request(url, (error, response, html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const temp = $('.col-md-12.col-lg-12.col-xs-12.padding-none.job-container.jobs-on-hover')
        temp.each(function (i, e) {
            console.log($(this).children('.latest-jobs-title.font-16.margin-none.inline-block').text());        // its printing empty lines
        });
    }
})
```

**HTML INspect Code**
There are multiple elements similar the the class below which I am fetching in the above code.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 padding-none job-container
jobs-on-hover">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 job-desc-block"
    style="margin-top:11px;">
    <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 col-lg-11 job_listing_alignment"><div
            class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 padding-none"><a
                href="https://www.freshersworld.com/jobs/junior-project-fellow-jobs-in-dhanbad-ism-dhanbad-1230705"
                target="_blank" title="ISM Dhanbad Recruitments"><h3
                    class="latest-jobs-title font-16 margin-none
                    inline-block"><span>ISM Dhanbad</span></h3></a><div>Junior
                Project Fellow</div><div class="qualification-block"><span
                    class="pull-left" title="Education Qualification"><svg
                        viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="icon-16-16"><use
                            xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            xlink:href="#icon-qualification-svg"></use></svg></span><span
                    class="qualifications display-block modal-open"><span
                        class="bold_elig">BE/B.Tech</span>, <span
                        class="bold_elig">ME/M.Tech</span>, <span
                        class="bold_elig">MSc</span></span></div></div></div><div
        class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-lg-1 padding-right-none
        padding-left-none job-desc-right"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12
            col-lg-12 text-ago" style="margin-top:5px;"><span title="Job
                posted on"><svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="icon-16-16"><use
                        xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        xlink:href="#icon-clock-svg"></use></svg></span><span
                class="ago-text">22h</span></div></div></div><div
    class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 view-apply-container"><div
        class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-lg-9 padding-none padding-top-5"><div
            class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5 padding-none"><span
                class="pull-left" title="Job Location"><svg viewBox="0 0 16
                    16" class="icon-16-16"><use
                        xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        xlink:href="#icon-location-svg"></use></svg></span><span
                class="job-location display-block modal-open"><span><span><span><a
                                class="bold_font"
                                href="/jobs-in-dhanbad/9999015062">Dhanbad</a></span></span></span></span></div><div
            class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 padding-none"><span
                title="Last Date for Job Application"><svg viewBox="0 0 16
                    16" class="icon-16-16"><use
                        xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        xlink:href="#icon-date-svg"></use></svg></span><span
                class="display-none">2021-06-19</span><span
                class="last-date">Last Date</span><span
                class="padding-left-4">27 Jun 21</span></div></div><div
        class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3 padding-none"><a
            href="https://www.freshersworld.com/jobs/junior-project-fellow-jobs-in-dhanbad-ism-dhanbad-1230705"
            target="_blank" class="view-apply-button
            view-apply-button-1230705">View &amp; Apply</a></div></div></div>
```

I want to get text for the class element **ago-text**

Comment: Need to see the HTML to know why your targeting isn't working.

Comment: @selfagency I have updated the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you want to use the `.find()` method instead of the `.children()` method. `.children()` only goes down one level in the DOM tree, while `.find()` descends through all the children of the element's children. Also, you only need to specify `.job-container` and `.latest-jobs-title`. You don't need all the Bootstrap styles in your query selector.